# Adding middleware in jest hangs the test | RTK query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, rtk-query

so I'm testing a react component where RTK-query is used. but when I configure store with middle, the test just hangs and does nothing. only timer keeps increasing.

Im not able to come up with any solution.

here is dumbed down version of my code:

**dataApi.js**

```
export const dataApi= createApi({
  reducerPath:'somepath',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getDataById: builder.query({
      query: (dataID) => ({
        url: `${endpoint}/${dataID}`,
        method: 'GET',
      }),
    })
  })
});
```

**component.js**

```
/*Imports */
function Component() {
useGetDataByIdQuery(params.id);
/*other logic*/

   return <> {JSX}</>
}
```

**component.test.js**

```
/*Imports */

let mockdata = { id: '123' };
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: () => mockdata,
  useRouteMatch: () => ({ url: '/data/123' }),
}));

jest.spyOn(dataApi, 'useGetDataByIdQuery').mockImplementation(() => (
  {
    isLoading: false,
    data: {}
  }));

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [dataApi.reducerPath]: dataApi.reducer,
   
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(dataApi.middleware),
});

test('should render wrapper correctly', () => {
    expect(<Provider store={store}><Component/></Provider>).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

if I remove the middleware, it gives me error that middleware is needed.

Comment: Just as a heads up: `expect(<Provider store={store}><Component/></Provider>).toMatchSnapshot();` will not test anything, since it does not render the component. It just tests that writing `<Component>` is `<Component>`, which is always true in React. You need to use something like `@testing-library/react`.

Comment: As for this dumbed-down version: apart from that, nothing looks wrong with it. Maybe you need to share something that is closer to what you are actually doing, or that you at least can reproduce your problem with?